# Having trouble writing python code to score runs in cribbage

Tags: python

The way my code is now it counts every kind of run correctly except double runs with a length of 3, can anyone help me understand why? With double runs of 3 it will not store the extra value in the duplicate_values list and I can't figure out how to make it work

```
def count_runs(card_values):
    all_values = []
    duplicate_values = []
    for i, value in enumerate(card_values):
        if value in all_values:
            if value not in duplicate_values:
                duplicate_count = card_values.count(value)
                if duplicate_count == 2:
                    duplicate_values.append(value)
                elif duplicate_count == 3:
                    duplicate_values += [value, value]
        else:
            all_values.append(value)

    all_values.sort()
    run_points = 0
    run_length = 1

    for i in range(1, len(all_values)):
        if all_values[i] == all_values[i-1]:
            continue
        if all_values[i] == all_values[i-1] + 1:
            run_length += 1
        else:
            if run_length >= 3:
                if len(duplicate_values) == 1 and duplicate_values[0] in range(all_values[i-run_length], all_values[i-1]+1):
                    run_points += run_length * 2
                elif len(duplicate_values) == 2:
                    if duplicate_values[0] == duplicate_values[1] and duplicate_values[0] in range(all_values[i-run_length], all_values[i-1]+1):
                        run_points += run_length * 3
                    elif duplicate_values[0] != duplicate_values[1] and all(x in range(all_values[i-run_length], all_values[i-1]+1) for x in duplicate_values):
                        run_points += run_length * 4
                    else:
                        run_points += run_length
                else:
                    run_points += run_length
            run_length = 1
            duplicate_values = []
    if run_length >= 3:
        if len(duplicate_values) == 1 and duplicate_values[0] in range(all_values[-run_length], all_values[-1]+1):
            run_points += run_length * 2
        elif len(duplicate_values) == 2:
            if duplicate_values[0] == duplicate_values[1] and duplicate_values[0] in range(all_values[-run_length], all_values[-1]+1):
                run_points += run_length * 3
            elif duplicate_values[0] != duplicate_values[1] and all(x in range(all_values[-run_length], all_values[-1]+1) for x in duplicate_values):
                run_points += run_length * 4
            else:
                run_points += run_length
        else:
            run_points += run_length

    print("Duplicate Values: ", duplicate_values)
    return run_points
```

I've tried the code with every other type of run and it works but with a double run of 3 it doesn;t store the extra value

Comment: Suggestion: Use `collections.Counter()` to count the duplicates.

Comment: You can use `itertools.combinations` to check all combinations of 6, 5, 4 and 3 cards.  That will return 2, 3, or 4 for a double, triple, or double-double run of 3.  If you get a run of 6, you don't have to check the rest.